# Android couldnt send attachement via email (gmail & other email clients)

Tags: android, email, gmail

i couldn't find help in related questions... so:
i try to send an email with an attachement with the following code:

```
String pdfName = "filename.pdf";
    File filelocation = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), pdfName);
    Uri path = Uri.fromFile(filelocation);
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setType("application/pdf");
    String to[] = {"email@email.com"};
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));
```

all works fine, i can choose an emailclient and the emailclient opens a new email with all things filled in. But after i send the email, i'm gettin an error "Couldn't send attachement" (Emailclient = Gmail). Same with GMX as emailclient ("This attachement is not supported").
Please help me.

**EDIT:**

I resolved my problem. The path of the pdf File was not correct. I also included a File chooser. Here is my solution:

```
private static final int PICK_FROM_GALLERY = 101;
static Uri URI = null;

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {  
    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.sendEmail){
        openGallery();
    }

    return true;
}

public void openGallery(){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("*/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_GALLERY);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == PICK_FROM_GALLERY && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        String fname = data.getDataString();
        URI = Uri.parse(fname);

        sendMail();
    }
}

private void sendMail(){
    if(URI != null) {
        try {
            final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"janssen.mark@gmx.de"});
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Database");
            if (URI != null) {
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, URI);
            }
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Im Anhang befindet sich die Datenbank als PDF-Datei.");
            this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Sending email..."));
        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Request failed: " + throwable.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is the pdf file attaching before u hit 'send' ? if so, try to open the pdf file before hitting send and verify that the attached pdf file can be opened (before trying to send)

Comment: also, what is the size of the pdf file?

Comment: @chornge ty for your responds! Sorry for my late answers. Your first hint helped me! The path of the pdf file was generated falsly. I will add my solution. Thanks!